# Unresolved inclusion: <glib.h> in Eclipse autotools project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, autotools, glib

I have an autotools project which detects the location of `glib` headers in its configure script and appends the needed flags to the `CPPFLAGS` variable in generated makefiles:

```
CPPFLAGS = -pthread -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include
```

How do I tell Eclipse to honor these flags in an Autotools Eclipse project? I found only one location in the project properties, which is: `Autotools -> Configure Settings -> configure/Advanced -> Additional command-line options`. I tried to add my `CPPFLAGS` there, but it didn't have any effect. After full rebuild the problem marker `Unresolved inclusion: <glib.h>` didn't go away.

Actually, it would be logical to have a per-file CFLAGS setting.

```
sh -c "/home/il/workspace/rappop6/configure CXXFLAGS=\"-g -O0\" CFLAGS=\"-g -O0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include\"" 
options=CXXFLAGS=-g -O0 CFLAGS=-g -O0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include
...
config.status: config.h is unchanged
[Operation successful]


15:41:20 **** Incremental Build of configuration debug for project rap ****
make all
...
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/il/workspace/rappop6/build-debug'

15:41:58 Build Finished (took 38s.723ms)
```